# Codeigniter 3 HMVC: unable to load session library

Tags: php, codeigniter, hmvc, codeigniter-hmvc

Here is the folder structure in `modules` library

1. users->controllers->Users.php

   users->config->autoload.php
2. welcome->controllers->Welcome.php

**autoload.php**

```
$autoload = array(
    'helper'    => array('url', 'form'),
    'libraries' => array('session')
);
```

**Welcome.php**  (located in modules/welcome/Welcome.php)

```
class Welcome extends MX_Controller {
    
   public function index()
    {
       //load module
       $this->load->module(array('users'));
    }
}
```

I will get the following error :

```
Unable to locate the specified class: Session.php
```

Note:
`url` and `form` libraries are loaded correctly

Answer (score 0):

In config/autoload.php file put below line

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database','form_validation','session');
```

Its work fine for me.

Comment: It should works :(

You try this one also
<code>class Welcome extends CI_Controller
{
  public function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->library->load('session');
  }

  ..........
}
</code>

Comment: But loading another modules i need to extend MX_Controller class

Comment: Look at my question welcome.php file is in modules/welcome/controllers folder not in applications/controllers folder

Comment: This may be the reason why the session path not configure properly.

Comment: Nop its not the issue

Answer (score 0):

please load session in index function

```
$this->load->library('session');
```

Add this part in your function